# Get browser to remember a:visited link until browser is closed

Tags: css, anchor

I have used `a:visited` CSS for my web application, but the browser remember its history for unlimited time.

How can I set this time till the browser is closed?

Comment: "You can't" is not the whole truth. You can with JS, but not CSS or HTML alone

Answer (score 2):

That is a browser setting, nothing you can influence with CSS.

Alternatives:

- Make the links “different” for each browsing session, f.e. by appending a random GET parameter/query string value, or
- do not use `:visited` in the first place, but keep track of clicked links via JavaScript and sessionStorage or a cookie, and then set a class on those elements every time a page is loaded, to achieve the formatting you want for that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. How long a browser keeps a URL in its history is entirely up to the browser and there are no APIs that allow a website to influence it.